# how to read only first line of a file

Tags: jquery

Using `.get()` is it possible to read only the first line of a .txt file?

something like:

```
jQuery.get('file.txt', function(data) {
   alert(data);
   //process text file line by line
   $('#div').html(data.replace('\n','<br>'));
});
```

but read only the first line?

Any other suggestion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might be a little faster than the version with `split`, as it won't split the whole `data` string, but instead it just searches for first newline.

```
data.substr(0, data.indexOf("\n"));
```

Comment: Yep, this could be a lot faster than my split method :)

Answer (score 5):

Split the contents of the file into lines, then retrieve the first element.

```
alert(data.split('\n')[0]);
```

Haven't tested, but should work.

Comment: +1 thanks, is there a more 'faster' way of doing this? (the file may contain looots of lines...)

Comment: With javascript, I doubt. Parse the file with php and return only the first line. Why does the user have to wait for all the file to download, when it could be done on the server side.